# What is the quickest way to create .sln file for website?

Tags: visual-studio

I've downloaded [MyWSAT](http://mywsat.codeplex.com/) to review but there is no solution or project files for Visual Studio 2012. So I've created a new solution and have attempted to `Add_Existing Items` to the new project, however, this won't auto add new folders so I have to manually set up all folders then add the files manually.

I just wanted to know if there is a quicker way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a solution.
2. Create a project for the website.
3. Paste the files in the same folder as the project.
4. Go back to VS and click the "Show All Files" icon above the solution explorer and include all the files.

Assuming there isn't more configuration necessary, that should work out fine. This is exempt of connection strings, security permissions, etc. but the files are all there and should render fine.

However, this really only works well for a classic ASP website. MVC takes a lot more than that (including wiring up controllers and views) unless those files are included in these "existing files" already.

Comment: Thank you. It was the step "Show All Files" that I missed when first attempting this as none of the files/folders were showing.